# Forward delete using Apple keyboard

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard

How to do a forward delete in Mac, like <-backspace on windows keyboard?

Answer (score 34):

> a forward delete in Mac, like <-backspace on windows

A Forward Delete on a Mac is *not* the Backspace on Windows, but is the Delete on a Windows keyboard. The Backspace on a Windows keyboard is called Delete on a Mac.

On a Mac, the Delete key is labeled "`delete`" or shows some left arrow (and ⌫ in the menus). The Forward Delete is labeled "⌦" or "`del`" (not "`delete`"), or "`delete` ⌦". If no such key is present, one can hold down Fn while pressing Delete.

[image: Delete and Forward Delete on Mac keyboards]

```
                Windows      Mac
backspace  /  ⌫  /  <⏤      <⏤  /  delete     /  ⌫
         delete  /  del      del  /  delete ⌦  /  ⌦  /  fn + delete
```

Not seeing the funny characters? See the note on using "Arial Unicode MS" at [Get Dingbats to appear in Firefox 3?](https://superuser.com/questions/14087/get-dingbats-to-appear-in-firefox-3)

While we're at the topic of keyboards: Macs don't use [Alt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alt_key), but use [Option](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Option_key). Up till recently, the Option key was labeled with the funny ⌥, representing the [pull-out plastic card](http://www.guidebookgallery.org/extras/spotlights/lisa/photos/vcf80/) situated under the Lisa keyboard. The latest keyboards no longer show that symbol, but only "option", while ⌥ is still shown in menu shortcuts. Likewise, Control has always been shown in the menus as ⌃ ([up arrowhead](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2303/), not Shift-6 which yields ^, being the [circumflex](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/005e)), but was never shown on the keyboard using that symbol either. Makes one wonder why the Command key is still also labeled ⌘ on today's keyboards...

The Option key on Mac keyboards is *also* labeled "alt", just in case you're controlling some Windows or Linux machine, either remotely, or by booting your Intel machine into another operating system. So, a Mac never uses Alt, but always uses Option. They just happen to be the same key. See also Apple's [Switch 101: On Windows, I used to...](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2514)

Comment: New Apple computers have an alt key. The option key is also labeled as alt.

Comment: The Alt *label* has been there for many years, but my point is that on Mac OS that is still not an Alt *key*. I've changed my answer to make my *The Alt label is really only there for running Windows and Linux applications* even more clear.

Answer (score 20):

Fn + Delete.

Also, check out some common [Mac Keyboard Shortcuts](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1343)

Answer (score 9):

Fn + Delete

Fn + Delete will delete the character to the right of the cursor, while Delete will delete the character to the left.

I believe you want to Fn + Delete

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Fn+Delete for forwards delete, there is also Ctrl+D (depending on the app).

Since Mac OS X has a Command key for shortcuts, that frees up the Ctrl key for... Control key sequences. Pressing the emacs shortcuts such as Ctrl+D works in most text boxes in most applications. (Btw Ctrl+K, Ctrl+Y do the same thing as emacs too.)

Comment: The powerful `ctrl-[A-Z]` text editing shortcut suite of [emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/refcards/pdf/refcard.pdf) is also widely available within macOS, e.g. `ctrl-k` to delete from cursor til line end, etc…

→ See the official [Mac Keyboard shortcuts](https://support.apple.com/HT201236#:~:text=Control-A).

**Thrilled to discover this!**

Mac user since 1992, using loads of productivity tweaks ever since. Discovered that suite by co-incidence after cleaning my key caps and then testing my keys in `TextEdit` in combo with modifier keys, eventually came here!



Answer (score 0):

Hold down Fn and press Backspace.

Comment: Backspace is called Delete on a Mac.

Answer (score 0):

On most Mac laptops the "Fn" key (at the bottom left of the keyboard) followed by the "delete" key performs a forward delete.

Comment: it's actually in the group above the arrow keys on the apple keyboards that include a number keypad.

Comment: It's not only laptops, but also the wireless keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to <kbd>fn</kbd><kbd>backspace</kbd>, the full-size Apple keyboard has a dedicated delete key, beneath <kbd>fn</kbd> and to the right of the return key.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>. This is especially useful if you want to remap the <kbd>fn</kbd> to be more *functional*.

I like to remap <kbd>fn</kbd> to <kbd>control</kbd>, because the <kbd>fn</kbd> key has no use besides forward delete, whereas, <kbd>control</kbd> has many applications but is fairly inconvenient to press on laptop Mac keyboards. A program that does this is [**DoubleCommand**](http://doublecommand.sourceforge.net/).