# Assign Mac OS X shortcut to left Alt key only

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts

I'd like to assign some shortcut in MAC OS X. But I want to limit to Left Alt only. When I'm assigning it now, both alts do work.

How do I limit it for one side only?

Comment: I'm afraid this might not be possible natively, but check this topic, you may have better results! http://superuser.com/questions/55954/is-there-a-good-app-for-key-bindings-and-key-macros-on-mac-os-x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en) to assign them to some unused key combinations first:

`<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::A, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L | ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::F19, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L</autogen>`

Without `| ModifierFlag::NONE` ⌃⌥A would also be changed to ⌃⌘F19.

See the source for the [key code values](https://github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook/blob/master/src/bridge/generator/keycode/data/KeyCode.data) and [predefined settings](http://raw.github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook/master/Tests/lib/string/data/checkbox.xml).