# Can't type the tilde (~) character in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, keyboard, keyboard-layout

This is a new problem that I did not have a few weeks ago.

I have a Logitech Illuminated Keyboard running on Mac OS X 10.6 (Snow Leopard).

The problem is that I cannot type a tilde (`~`).

Instead when I press the tilde <kbd>~</kbd> I get this character:

```
§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§
```

I cannot for the life of me figure this out, except that I vaguely remember I can asked to redetect the Mac keyboard layout for this keyboard and I think i chose the wrong one.

Now I get this weird character when pressing tilde. How can I fix this? Or how can I redetect this keyboard layout?

Comment: What keyboard (Input Source) is selected in "Language and Text" in your System Preferences? Of note the character you're printing can normally be inserted using Option-6 (the section character)

Comment: On some Apple keyboards, a backtick/tilde key is left from "Z", on others it's left from "1" (and the other position is then "§/±"). And there's probably more options here. So: where is it on your Logitech keyboard?

Comment: Makes me wonder: can you somehow still switch between application windows? (Command-Tab to switch between applications, Command-tilde to switch between the windows of an application)?

Comment: Arjan: No i cannot command-tilde between windows. The character output doesnt work in any form for me.

Comment: @Chealion: Option-6 gives me: § - Nice try though

Comment: I'm experiencing something very strange with my Mac and keyboard combo. It's a Canadian-French keyboard. In OS X, the OS insists on priting § and ± instead of ` (backtick) and ~ (tilde). However, inside of my Virtualbox VMs, they act perfectly fine. Totally mysterious behaviour! I gotta swap keyboards, soon! XD Oh, and, I've tried a variety of US and Canadian "language/keyboard" settings. Haven't been able to get the US mapping to work on this keyboard at all, except inside of VMs for some reason!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Don't know if you are still reading this but if you download a program called `Ukelele`, you can make custom keyboard maps.

Then you need to put the keyboard map into `~/Library/Keyboard Layouts/`, log off and then back in.

Once you have done this you can choose your custom keyboard layout and you will be able to use the ~ key without any problem (I'm using a Logitech illuminated keyboard using the default Logitech-UK keymap that comes with `Ukelele` and everything works).

Answer (score 29):

On a keyboard with that <kbd><>|</kbd> button between the left <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Z</kbd>, holding down <kbd>Shift</kbd> and pressing that button works on my end. Neither <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd> nor <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> do the trick on my end.

Comment: Phew, that worked! I'm using a Danish keyboard and US layout.

Comment: I am using a Dutch keyboard with US layout, and this worked.

Comment: On Swiss German keyboard with US layout the combination is ⇧+<>

Answer (score 27):

If someone else is still interested in how to swap the `§` key with `~`, I use [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) to do that and it's pretty easy to use. Just look for that option which is included in the default ones among others.

[image]

It can also be used to remap other keys if you want. For example, you can use hjkl keys to emulate the arrow keys (vim users will love it).

Comment: +1 This solution worked straight away for me, it is the simplest solution ever, thanks!. On the other hand, using Ukelele didn't work for me, the keyboard layout bundle is not recognized.

Comment: ...so 6 years later Karabiner-Elements is significantly different; how do I do this now?

Comment: @JasonS, apply this Simple Modification swapping "non_us_backslash" and "grave_accent_and_tilde" keys: [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/oOkm0tp.png)

Comment: Don't forget to go to "Devices" menu and activate the "Modify events" toggle for your keyboard, it wasn't on by default for me despite the key modifications

Answer (score 27):

The correct way to fix your problem is to get your Mac to re-detect your keyboard type.

Open your Keyboard preferences (System preferences → Keyboard) and on the bottom left side you will see a "Change Keyboard Type" button.

[image: Keyboard - System preferences]

Click on it and follow the instructions.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer, and the best for mojave!

Comment: Had the same issue, and this helped! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Indeed this is the correct answer.  The others are band-aids

Comment: This option is missing on Monterey 12.4 :(

Comment: Thank you! That should be the correct answer as it does not require the setup of extra tools.

Comment: "Keyboard not recognized" using that menu for me in Monterey 12.6.2 M1 chipset

Answer (score 12):

With Karabiner-Elements, it can be done by swapping `non_us_backslash` and `grave_accent_and_tilde` keys like so:

[image: Karabiner-Elements Simple Modifications screenshot]

I needed this setup for my German keyboard which use with both English and German layout.

Comment: This worked for me - I would never have stumbled upon non_us_backslash - the other option key solutions won't work for me as I use both '`' and '~' all the time.

Comment: Funny since Karabiner Elements was the application for me that screwed it up. I had to quit Karabiner Elements to get the keyboard to work normally again. I have not changed this setting from karabiner elements. Of course I could do this and have both working, but I feel that Karabiner should not change this in the first place

Answer (score 10):

Usually <kbd>~</kbd> character is associated with "n" letter. So you can do <kbd>~</kbd> using <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> keys.

When you do not know how to type a character, you should try the keyboard viewer in the last tab of the "langage and text" icon of the prefs panel.

Comment: Protest ;-) There's no "Alt" in OS X. See http://superuser.com/questions/25005/forward-delete-using-apple-keyboard/25022#25022 ;-) (Option-N followed by n or N can be used to get ñ and Ñ. But indeed, Option-N followed by space yields just `~`. Still, Brock's keyboard layout does not match the actual keyboard.)

Comment: Sorry, on french layout the "option" is also co-named "alt"

Comment: I edited the answer to take your comment into account. Thanks !

Comment: *on french layout the "option" is also co-named "alt"* -- yes, on my Macs as well, but that's not *used* in OS X. Of course, it's not a real issue (let's get world peace first). See that link I gave for some thoughts on "Backspace" and "Alt". I actually hope that French keyboards have a tilde key as well? I can't live without it, like using Command-~ to switch between application windows.

Comment: Yes, the alt thing is "Linux and Windows" related, your link is very well documented and interesting. Thanks for the reminder ^^. By the way, the French layout and the Apple-French layout are completely different. The ~ is not on the Apple-French : you need "Option + n"

Comment: Then how does one switch between application windows on a French keyboard? On other Apple keyboards, one would press Command-tilde. I hope this does not translate to Command-Option-N-space on a French keyboard?

Comment: On my layout option + n produces a ˜, which is different to the tilde, which is ~

Comment: @joshhunt, Your ˜ is http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/02dc/ which on my US keyboard is Shift-Option-N. Using that US layout, Option-N (without holding Shift) does not give me any character yet, but it shows a yellow ~ to indicate I can compose another character with it. Next, pressing N, n, A, a, O, o or space, yield Ñ, ñ, Ã, ã, Õ, õ or ~. (Also, keyboard viewer shows the changed characters after pressing Option-N. Holding down Shift with US Extended changes the character before the cursor, to even create q̃w̃ẽr̃t̃ỹ...̃) I guess things can be very different on some keyboards.

Comment: Try using the keyboard viewer when you want to type commands that use the ~ in the path day in day out - Not an ideal solution.

Answer (score 5):

On a Mac, tilde can be obtained using the key combination <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd>.

Let me stress that <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd> returns tilde `~`, whereas <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> returns tilde as character apice `˜`.

Comment: You're right that Alt+n gives ˜ which is not the true tilde, but Alt+5 gives me ∞. I'm using the UK keyboard layout on an American hardware keyboard.

Comment: If you want the real tilde, try Alt+n and then press the space bar...your "fake" tilde will be converted to a "real" tilde ;-)

Comment: @ClintEastwood ˜ is not ~...

Answer (score 5):

What characters you get by typing with <kbd>⌥</kbd> key, <kbd>⌃</kbd>, or combination of the two (there's also <kbd>⇧</kbd>, remember) depends on which language keyboard you use.

To find out all characters on your keyboard enable *Keyboard & Character Viewer* in *Input Sources* inside *Language & Text*.

With U.S. keyboard type <kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>`</kbd> (near the left Shift button).

Answer (score 2):

On my macbook air with **Danish keyboard layout**, <kbd>~</kbd>  key combination is <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>^</kbd>.

Comment: Works with a Swwedish (external) keyboard connected to a Mac Book Pro.

Comment: Does not work with UK keyboard layout on US hardware keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, on OSX 10.9.1 `~` on my German Airbook using US American layout is mapped to Shift and the key directly to its right.

Answer (score 2):

The best and easiest way is:

1. **<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>** <sub>**Obs.:** Between left</sub> **<kbd>Shift</kbd>** <sub>and</sub> **<kbd>z</kbd>**
2. Then **<kbd>`s p a c e`</kbd>**

[image: show on keyboard]

Comment: The answer I needed basically I do shift + > = ~ I got Tilda. Yeyyy

Answer (score 0):

In my MacBook (2007) keyboard I get the <kbd>~</kbd> by combining <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> (the next key to the right).

Answer (score 0):

I set up [KeyRemap4MacBook](https://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/) application and type `~` with `shift+escape`

[image: setting tilde key to shift escape in KeyRemap4MacBook]

Answer (score 0):

And for those amoung us using a mac keyboard with **Spanish keyboard layout**, <kbd>~</kbd>  key combination is <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>ñ</kbd> (the Spanish ñ, instead of n).

Answer (score 0):

You can remap using this file:

```
~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.example.KeyRemapping.plist
```

- [https://chuyeow.wtf/2020/06/24/remapping-keys-on-macos](https://web.archive.org/web/20230404211541/https://chuyeow.wtf/2020/06/24/remapping-keys-on-macos)
- https://gist.github.com/chuyeow/2ab2d3e6a649389cea58f4d31f7f6d53

You can use this tool to generate the configuration:

- https://hidutil-generator.netlify.app/

You just need these two lines in the "UserKeyMapping" section:

```
{
    "HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc": 0x700000064,
    "HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst": 0x700000035
}
```

This will map the "Keyboard Non-US" to be "Keyboard Grave Accent and Tilde".

Answer (score 0):

For me the answer was to do the System preferences -> Keyboard -> "Change Keyboard Type" operation in the answer https://superuser.com/a/1277702/501186 - BUT, instead of using the ISO option it suggested, I needed to choose the ANSI option.

Even though I'm in the UK, all my keycaps now reflect the right values.

I'm using a Logitech K860. This never used to be a problem, until my keyboard started randomly disconnecting and I performed a reset on it.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem where I have a German keyboard with an english keyboard layout and the window switcher in Mac OS X was supposed to be activated by pressing <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>~</kbd>.

However, when I pressed it, it didn't work as expected. While some previous answers in here work, they don't apply to Mac OS X 13.1 Ventura since the system preferences menu has changed. I was able to fix the problem by going to System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Keyboard shortcuts -> Keyboard and then reset the ”Move focus to status menus” to <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>.

[image]