# How to make a tilde on a spanish keyboard set to English?

Tags: mac, keyboard-layout, english

That's right. I bought a Spanish computer, and set it to English. And I can't find the tilde.

This is Mac OS X

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/64072/cant-type-tilde-character-in-mac-os-x

Answer (score 13):

With a spanish keyboard and the Spanish (ISO) layout I get the <kbd>~</kbd> character with <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>ñ</kbd>.

Answer (score 4):

Spanish keyboards lack the <kbd>~</kbd> key if I remember correctly. You could try <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>n</kbd> followed by a <kbd>space</kbd> or <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd> followed by space. On a Spanish (Latin) keyboard it should be <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd>

If **everything** fails activate the `Unicode Input Source` in the OS X Preferences. You can then hold down <kbd>option</kbd> and type: <kbd>0</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd> <kbd>7</kbd> <kbd>E</kbd>. <sub>I have to switch a lot from the German Input Source and the Unicode Hex one. It isn't comfortable, but at least it works.</sub>

Comment: Wow great answer. But unfortunately none of those options worked. I'm looking for an app to take care of it now.