# How to type the backtick symbol on a windows keyboard connected to a mac laptop

Tags: windows, macos, keyboard, logitech-keyboard

As the title pretty much says how do you type the backtick symbol on a windows keyboard connected to a mac? In my case, I'm using a Logitech G413.

I know how to type it on mac, I know how to type it on Windows but I don't know how to type it on a windows keyboard connected to mac.

The symbol in question: ` (backtick).

Comment: My work-around for any kind of machine, for any kind of operating system and for any kind of input language is to find an app similar to _Character Map_ (`C:\Windows\System32\charmap.exe`) from the Microsoft Windows family of operating systems. Try to find its counterpart in the Mac world. Search for the back-tick, copy-and-paste it and then at least you can move on with whatever you are doing, for the moment.

Comment: Thanks for the character map hint. Of course, as a workaround, I can type the backtick on the mac keyboard for the time being. That being said it's a bit tedious :D

Comment: Maybe it is simply not possible what you want to achieve. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent) has a certain section called as _Technical notes_ that explain how to obtain the backtick on various operating systems. Try to see if you can get something from there.

Answer (score 1):

After a few more googling attempts [this](https://superuser.com/a/1277702/415815) answer helped me. At first identification, I clicked on the European standard since the keyboard (and me) are from Europe. But that turned the Tilda key into some random key. During the second time when I chose the ANSII keyboard, the Tilda key got mapped correctly and now I can backtick to my heart's content.