# How to type the tilde '~' with an apple international keyboard?

Tags: macos, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I want the type the  <kbd>`</kbd> and <kbd>~</kbd> on US keyboard with a US international layout on macOS BigSur 11.2.3

Currently the key returns: `§` and `±`

I want to do this without installing  more  apps. How do I simply remap?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't Type Tilde character in Mac OS X](https://superuser.com/questions/64072/cant-type-tilde-character-in-mac-os-x)

Comment: No it does not, since it proses an other tools.

Comment: Precisely which keyboard do you have? Post a photo if you're not sure.  If it's an ISO, then §± are left of 1, and `~ left of z. If you're trying to use US-PC, then switch back to regular US or UK, depending on precisely which keyboard it is. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/417995/how-to-output-tilde-directly

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question however I stumbled across it while searching for a different problem.

To type a tilde or any other symbol on US International, you type the letter and then press <kbd>space</kbd> to confirm. If you don't press the <kbd>space</kbd> certain letters become accents etc.

As for your keyboard you just need to make sure the layout set in system preferences is the same as your keyboard, if the key next to one is `§` and `±` set your layout to U.S. and then the tilde and `` ` `` are next to `Z`.