# Change modifier keys (Option, Alt, Ctrl, etc.) on Mac OS X according to specific applications

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout

I'd like my Option and Alt keys to switch places in certain applications. Is there any way to change the modifier keys according specific applications in Mac OS X?

Alternatively; is there "an application for that"?

Comment: Option and Alt [are the same key](http://superuser.com/questions/25005/forward-delete-using-apple-keyboard/25022#25022). Is this just a mistake, or do you really somehow simultaneously want both the OS X Option *and* the Windows/Linux Alt to sit on different keys?

Comment: I guess it's a typo and he meant "option", "command" and/or "control". Still, you have a point.

Comment: You can remap individual menu items of a specific application in *System Preferences » Keyboard » Keyboard Shortcuts » Applications*. Especially if you want to switch `Option` and `Control`, this might be a viable choice.

Answer (score 1):

I use Ukulele for a PC keymap (there are included Logitech keymaps for OSX86 users).
[DoubleCommand](http://doublecommand.sourceforge.net/) is a great app to swap Command, Option and Control, and it can correct the behavior of the Home/End keys on PC.

Answer (score 0):

You may build a different keymap and switch keymap when you switch application.
I don't know if [Ukelele](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&item_id=ukelele) allows you to change the position of the modifiers key, but if it doesn't I *guess* you still can edit the XML by hand.

(still, I think you'd better accept the proper keys rather than doing this dirty workaround)

Comment: You can't swap the modifier keys in a `.keylayout` (or with Ukelele). You could switch the keymaps under ⌥ and ⇧ for example, but that would only affect text output, not shortcuts in most cases. (⌘ and ⌃ don't usually even have output.)