# where is backspace key of Mac?

Tags: mac, keyboard, macbook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Forward delete using Apple keyboard](https://superuser.com/questions/25005/forward-delete-using-apple-keyboard)

I am using a MacBook Pro running Mac OS X 10.5. I am new to this development environment, and previously worked on Windows.

I am wondering what is the backspace key of Mac (i.e. which is used to delete the character previous to current cursor position in text editor)? Windows keyboard has a dedicated backspace key, but I did not find such a key on my MacBook Pro keyboard.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mac only has a backspace key. It does not have a "delete" key. (You can however, do <kbd>FN</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> and it will do the same thing as a Delete key on windows.

Comment: It's not really *called* a backspace on a Mac. See the duplicate questions.

Comment: @Arjan - Ah yes, but it actually does the same as a backspace

Comment: You're right: the question is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

The delete button actually acts as backspace. Pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Fel</kbd> will delete the character ahead.