# How can I remove url autocorrect entry in google chrome (windows)

Tags: windows-7, windows, google-chrome, autocomplete

The first time I used Chrome on this computer I mistakenly typed in the URL/Search textbox **"C/#"** instead of **"C#"** and now eveytime I write a sentence that starts with **"C#"** it "auto-corrects" it to the C/#, and since it's the first word in the URL box the browser thinks it's a protocol name (e.g http://, ftp://, etc...).

I read online that you can select the entry and press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>DELETE</kbd> but it won't work...

How can I remove it? 
Please help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove auto-complete field entries in Google Chrome](http://superuser.com/questions/171198/remove-auto-complete-field-entries-in-google-chrome)

Comment: @Tim Radcliffe I've seen this solution but it won't work

Comment: @TimRadcliffe Please see the accepted answer, it is not a duplicate...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't mistakenly type C/#, it's actually an older bug that resurfaced.

See https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=409845 (reported Sept 2).

Or [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=409845) (reported Aug 21st)

Another user had this problem too [here](https://superuser.com/questions/816921/clear-item-from-chrome-address-bar-autocomplete/816966#816966).

Chrome developers are already working on it so it should be fixed soon.

Comment: Oh really? How did you manage to find this? Anyway thanks a lot! I spend hours trying to solve it...