# How to remove specific URL from Opera address bar autocomplete?

Tags: opera, autocomplete, address-bar

How can I remove a specific URL from the address bar autocomplete? Using Opera 31.0.1889.174 on Windows 7.

I tried using the arrow down key to go to the specific entry and then hitting <kbd>Delete</kbd>.  Also tried <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd> neither seem to work.

**EDIT:**

Regarding the duplicate statement, this should be a separate question if the goal is to help people.  I don't think it's self-evident to all users of Opera that it is based on chromium and that therefore they should search for Chrome solutions to their Opera problems.  Furthermore the accepted answer of the referenced question does not in any way explain how to do what I asked. Finally, while Shift + Delete works in Chrome it does not work (at least for me) in Opera in removing items from the address bar autocomplete.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Clear item from Chrome address bar autocomplete](http://superuser.com/questions/816921/clear-item-from-chrome-address-bar-autocomplete)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Opera 48 now seems to allow you to delete URLs from the address bar's autocomplete.

From http://blogs.opera.com/desktop/2017/09/convert-measurements-currencies-time-zones-opera-48/

> **Clean up unwanted suggestions**
>
> The autocomplete feature can be helpful when we regularly visit (or
>   can’t quite remember the complete address of) a particular site, but
>   there can be some entries or suggestions which we want to get rid of.
>   For Windows and Linux platforms, Opera 48 allows you to delete URL
>   history suggestions for web pages or search entries from being
>   completed in the combined search and address bar. Whether that’s a
>   mistyped search or a page you want to forget about, you can now get
>   rid of it with just one click.
>
> Deletable search or page URLs will have an ‘X’ on the far-right end of
>   the entry in the search and address bar dropdown menu. No longer will
>   you have to dig through your history log to delete these entries.

If you have bookmarked a URL it won't be deletable. I have occasionally seen non-bookmarked URL's that appear to not be deletable. I'm not sure if this is a bug, user error, or some other quirk.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I have found is to find the item in your history, and delete  it from there. Then it will no longer be suggested in the url bar autocomplete.

A UX fail on Opera's part. For quite a while, anytime I loaded youtube it always loaded a specific video I once played several times in a row.