# On a Chromebook, how do I selectively delete Search entries from the Omnibox

Tags: google-chrome, search, chromebook, omnibox

What I already know:

- I have read about deleting URLs from the Omnibox on a Chromebook, that is use Shift+Delete (or Shift+Alt+Backspace on older chromebooks).
- I have also found a few articles about how to edit the Omnibox database from a browser other than Chrome on Mac, Linux, etc ([Clear item from Chrome address bar autocomplete](https://superuser.com/questions/816921/clear-item-from-chrome-address-bar-autocomplete/896715#896715)).

What I don't know:

- How do I delete a specific search entry from the Omnibox when I am on a Chromebook?

Limitations:

- If there's an extension for that, I prefer it be from someone I can trust.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was having this same issue (I think). The <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> wasn't doing anything on my Samsung Chromebook. Turns out I had saved the url as a bookmark (I'd bookmarked the page) and Chrome was using the bookmark to suggest autocompleting the url.

Deleted the bookmark and Chrome stopped suggesting it. Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

Hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>, then press <kbd>Backspace</kbd>.