# How to remove a particular link from the autocomplete list of desktop Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

Sometimes after I visit a wrongly inputed page more than once, Chrome will weirdly store it in the autocomplete bar from the location form (address bar? the one get focused when you click CMD+L on Mac).

What can I do to remove one from the list? Here in the red outline is the one I want to remove.

[image: how to remove it from Google Chrome?]

Answer (score 1):

**"What can I do to remove one from the list?"**

In both Chrome and Firefox, you can use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> to remove a selected (highlighted) autocomplete entry from the address and search bars.

Comment: This does not work in OSx, I'm trying to remove a "gitlab" entry that references "http://gitlab/" and have not been able to remove it.

Comment: @Webnet the duplicate link answer [How to remove one or all auto-complete text entries in Chrome?](http://superuser.com/a/175261) has specific instructions for a Mac ...