# How to remove Search autofill in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, autocomplete, google-search

It has already been asked about removing autofill URL entries in Chrome: [How to remove one or all auto-complete text entries in Chrome?](https://superuser.com/questions/175250/how-to-remove-one-or-all-auto-complete-text-entries-in-chrome)

In my case the question is how to remove the autofill SEARCH terms. The difference is that URL entries appear with a document icon and can be removed with Shift+Delete, but the same procedure doesn't work with entries shown next to a magnifying glass.

[image: screenshot]

In my case I cannot remove the "192.168.I.I" entry.

As additional info, I get that suggestion on different computers, and I found out that it appeared also on one where I never logged in my Google account (I installed Chrome, and shortly after there it was).

How can I clean my account or computer completely from that suggestion? or is it maybe an autofill that Google recommends because lots of people wrongly type?

Answer (score 1):

I thought about searching the specific autofill entries instead of searching generically for ways to remove suggested entries and I found a [discussion](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/websearch/A1lg_HTBK5g) about it on google forums.

It looks like it's not related to my history or my specific computer but it's an autofill that Google genuinely recommends. It is not related to my account or computer in any way and that explains why I got it in a clean computer.

The only solution is to disable search suggestions altogether by adding a custom search engine with no search suggestions using this URL as search engine: https://www.google.com/search?complete=0&q=%s

Disabling autofill altogether on Chrome would also remove autofill known URLs.

I left a feedback to Google recommending the banning of similar wrong autofill entries from their databases.