# Creating iTunes listing including "Where" information?

Tags: itunes

Although iTunes produces a very good comprehensive listing of all music, which can be copied and pasted into Excel to give a database of music, unfortunately it does not include "where" information as shown on the "Get Info" summary.

As, in my own case, music files are in a number of different locations (drives and folders) I would like to be able to identify, quickly and simply, duplicate tracks as the last column in the Excel listing.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: As per [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/223905/filtering-itunes-library-items-by-file-location), it doesn't seem to be possible using only iTunes. It might be possible to use PowerTunes (see my reply there) for your problem.

Comment: Daniel  thanks for this   unfortunately Power Tunes is a Mac only program and I use a pc with windows 7   (problem has now been solved)

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can see you entire iTunes library in MS Excel

1. Export the iTunes library as a TEXT file. This will give you the WHERE information as well. Lets say you call this `MyMusic.TXT`
2. This file is actually a CSV file, so let's change the file's extension from .TXT to .CSV
3. Simply open it in EXCEL, and you will be able to use it like a spreadsheet in EXCEL.

**Note:** If you want to, you can now save this file as an XLS file.

Comment: OK and how do I read an xml file and transfer the data to an excel sheet

Comment: @Hugh - answer changed.

Comment: @Hugh : If the answer has fully answered the question, then consider marking it as an Accepted Answer by clicking on the outline of a checkmark to the left of the answer. This lets other people know that it has been answered.