# Utility to browse, preview, and delete PDFs

Tags: windows, pdf

I need a utility that lets me browse a folder of PDFs, preview them (even one page of one document at a time), and then quickly delete the current one in view if I don't want it any longer. I've tried xPlorer2, but the preview window holds a handle to the PDF you're on and won't let you delete it.

Comment: In Preview on a Mac, simply hitting Command-Delete [will do the trick](http://superuser.com/questions/222006/mac-osx-preview-disable-the-command-backspace-move-to-trash-keyboard-shortcut).

Comment: @Arjan Heck, you don't even need Preview--QuickLook and the Finder can do it all on their own.

Comment: Doh! I"m using this on a Windows PC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2007/02/27/14001.aspx

Seems to work well on any windows

Comment: I'm not sure how to use this plugin particular applications, like xPlorer2.