# Is it possible to change or override the default keyboard shortcuts in Finder?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, finder

I would like to override the keyboard-shortcut for a particular built-in action in finder (OS X 10.6.7).

An example would be to override the <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> for a New Finder Window to some other action, say Open a blank Text document.

I can create the service for opening a blank Text document in automator - and I can map a new keyboard shortcut for this - but the new keyboard shortcut will not override a default keyboard shortcut.

I do not want to install any 3rd party applications (like QuickSilver).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try to remove the keyboard shortcut from Finder, as per [this answer of mine, in collaboration with @Arjan](https://superuser.com/questions/222006/mac-osx-preview-disable-the-command-backspace-move-to-trash-keyboard-shortcut/222053#222053):

```
defaults write com.apple.Finder NSUserKeyEquivalents -dict-add "New Window" nil
```

<sup>(not on OS X right now, replace text with actual label)</sup>

Maybe then the keyboard shortcut for the Service will work.

Comment: So this worked beautifully - and now i know about the NSUserKeyEquivalents - whoot!  I found a nice writeup on this website (http://www.hoboes.com/Mimsy/hacks/disabling-quit-rewriting/) that gave me a better feel around this and how to use the -dict-add and undo whatever mess I might make while experimenting.  I actaully miss the good old Windows+E to pull up a nice explorer window and have mapped Command+E to open a finder window.  Works perfectly! Thanks a bunch as my productivity just got a 3% boost!

Comment: @super Besides creating the "missing/resetting" shortcut, all other actions can be performed more comfortably from *System Preferences*. Also, `Command-E` is likely used by many applications, I suggest a shortcut that contains `Control` (e.g. `Ctrl-Opt-E` or `Ctrl-Command-E`), these are least likely to be in use, in my experience.

Comment: Thanks. This is _very_ useful. I always press Command+T in Finder, to disable it: `defaults write com.apple.Finder NSUserKeyEquivalents -dict-add "Add to Sidebar" nil`

Answer (score 7):

I had this same issue with wanting to change Finder's "Cycle Through Windows" default of <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd>.

By adding an application-specific shortcut in System Preferences > Keyboard, I was able to change the default *:

[image: system prefs keyboard shortcuts]

You can see this new shortcut reflected in Finder's menu:

[image: finder shortcut changed]

<sub>* I changed it to something I'd never use, as I wanted <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> for another purpose.</sub>

Comment: Best answer for me!

Comment: I did the same for safari for new tab, I can see new shortcut in menu but it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to change the default keyboard shortcut for Finder on your Mac. You can customize the shortcut by following these steps:

1. Open **System Preferences** on your Mac.
2. Click on **Keyboard**.
3. Select the **Shortcuts** tab.
4. Click on **App Shortcuts** in the left sidebar.
5. Click on the **+** button to add a new shortcut. It is at the bottom of the right pane and beside the minus symbol (which you will need to use to remove).
6. In the **Application** field, select Finder from the dropdown box. This means there is a wider variety of applications that you can assign shortcuts!
7. In the **Menu Title** field, type the **exact name** of the menu command whose shortcut you want to change. For example, if you want to change the shortcut for "Downloads" folder, type "Downloads" (without quotes).
8. In the **Keyboard Shortcut** field, press the keys you want to use for the new shortcut.
9. Click on **Add**.
   [image]

After following these steps, your new keyboard shortcut will be active in Finder. In the picture which I have shown, I have reused a shortcut key so it now appears for 'Downloads' and there is no shortcut key for 'Desktop'.

[image]

I hope this helps someone in year 2023 and thanks to Bing who helped me to contribute back this answer to this thread.