# Which Unicode characters do smilies like ٩(•̮̮̃•̃)۶ consist of?

Tags: unicode, emoticons

How do I make Unicode texts like the one in the title, or like the following, without resorting to copy+paste?

## ٩(-̮̮̃-̃)۶ ٩(●̮̮̃•̃)۶ ٩(͡๏̯͡๏)۶ ٩(-̮̮̃•̃).

As an aside, note that in your browser the above example [should look like](https://superuser.com/questions/52671/how-do-i-create-unicode-smilies-like/58534#58534):

[image: Expected rendering of Unicode smileys]

Comment: why don't you just copy/ paste?

Comment: I want to know how does it come in multiline fashion? take (●̮̮̃•̃) for example. Why do i get a feeling that it is in multiline?

Comment: http://www.reddit.com/r/unicode

Comment: I am :( that these smilies are broked in Chrome. they used to work...

Answer (score 198, accepted):

As for your confusion about multi-line: There are numerous [diacritics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic) at work here. Those are combining characters that get placed above or below other characters. If we dissect the specific smiley (●̮̮̃•̃) we get the following:

```
(   U+0028  Left Parenthesis (this is obvious)

●   U+25CF  Black Circle (this will be the left eye)

 ̮  U+032E  Combining breve below (this gets part of the mouth)
           The fact that it's placed slightly right of the circle is a
           font issue. Normally it should appear directly below the
           preceding character

 ̮  U+032E  Combining breve below (still part of the mouth)

 ̃   U+0303  Combining Tilde (this will be the left eyebrow)

•   U+2022  Bullet (right eye)

 ̃   U+0303  Combining Tilde (eyebrow)

)   U+0029  Right Parenthesis
```

It's some clever use of diacritic characters that creates the illusion of multiple lines here. Combining characters can be stacked, as seen with the breve, but usually the [results are less good](http://www.siao2.com/2006/02/17/533929.aspx).

You can paste the smileys into Word and by placing the cursor after a character and pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> you can cause the character to be replaced with its Unicode code point in hexadecimal. In the case of diacritics you first replace the diacritic and then can proceed with the base character (or still more diacritics if they are there). The other way around works too. You can enter 2022 and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and get a bullet point.

So for getting the smiley above you can use the following string of letters and numbers:

```
002825CF032E032E0303202203030029
```

paste it into Word and hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> every four places, beginning at the left.

***Note:*** In the preceding paragraphs I have used the hotkey <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> *exclusively. When not using Word but instead some variant of RichEdit (for example in WordPad) this becomes* <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> *instead. Also, as mentioned in the comments, for some people apparently it's* <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> *in Word, too. In the interest of brevity I will only talk about* <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, *but you should use whatever variant applies to you. Another method, mentioned in [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/55502/typing-strange-letters-w-o-numpad/55505#55505) would be to use* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> *which seems to work as well. Just in case there aren't enough options yet.*

***Note 2:*** In the overview of characters used for the smiley above the spacing seems off in some places. This had technical reasons and may differ from one browser to another. Also some combining characters tended to disappear which is why some of them are shifted to the right.

Comment: Or see "Insert Unicode characters via the keyboard?" at http://superuser.com/questions/47420/insert-unicode-characters-via-the-keyboard

Comment: And for those not seeing the funny characters: read about using "Arial Unicode MS" in "Get Dingbats to appear in Firefox 3?" at http://superuser.com/questions/14087/get-dingbats-to-appear-in-firefox-3

Comment: Arial Unicode MS is not a sane font to use: http://blogs.msdn.com/michkap/archive/2007/07/15/3890144.aspx ... in fact, the smileys display horribly here with Arial Unicode MS. Pasting them into word uses a mixture of Arial, Calibri and Cordia New. Please don't recommend Arial Unicode MS where it does more harm than good (almost everywhere, if we are to believe Michael Kaplan). Verdana also works well.

Comment: In Word 2007 (on XP), it seems to be Alt+X that does the conversion, not Alt+C.

Comment: Graham: incorporated into the answer. Or at least a little clarified. Perhaps I should just talk about "The Hotkey™" instead of giving any specific keystrokes ...

Comment: Wow, what an answer. Upvoted.

Comment: definitely an excellent answer.  upvoted.

Comment: Super :) info :)

Comment: Of note, the combining breve below no longer seems to have the claimed font issues in Chrome on OSX on 10.7.2 - Sadly, with the "mouths" placed correctly, this distorts a number of these smilies that rely on the combining characters to appear in incorrect spots :(

Answer (score 32):

Copy and paste:

## ◎ܫ◎

## ಠﭛಠ

## ⊙_ʘ

## ♨_♨

## ಠ_ಠ

Comment: teddy, om nom, hurr?, the goggles, and my all time fav unicode expression.

Comment: In what OS/browser does this look alright? (Not in any browser on my Mac or an old WinXP, though on WinXP Firefox does the best job only not displaying the 4th correctly.)

Comment: vista and 7, ie and chrome.

Comment: Opera renders everything perfectly on winXP.

(But then, I have a LOT of specialty fonts installed, as well as the Windows XP Multilanguage-User-Interface (MUI) pack).

Oh, on Win XP. Edit - Also seems to work in firefox for me, though not IE6.

Comment: Windows character map.

Comment: ಠ_ರೃ is a good one too

Comment: Ꙭ looks fun too. And even is a single character.

Answer (score 19):

If these are too complex, Unicode #263A (☺) and Unicode #2639 (☹) are supported by most OSes and browsers.

Answer (score 8):

As Johannes Rössel said , you can use this online editor to convert ascii characters to unicode / your preferable format and change it whenever you need.

[Online Unicode Converter](http://rishida.net/tools/conversion/)

Answer (score 5):

What do you mean? You're doing them already. Just look up the [Unicode characters](http://unicode.org/charts/) and start combining them in your way.