# How to input special characters w/o numpad?

Tags: windows, special-characters, numpad

How do I type special characters (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+0???) in Windows on a laptop without **any** kind of numeric keyboard (even not one accessed by FN)?

Right now I am using the NT 4 charmap (the XP one sucks), but does anyone know of a more efficient way?

Comment: So, you are using Windows XP?

Comment: @kinokijuf To me you picked a good way. find and 1 click as opposed to typing 4 things. What else could there be? Remapping, or creating shorts for some special charachters you use. using a International keyboard, or some super special OnScreenKeyboard that is better than the charmap. Having a big clipboard of whole "Words" to paste without retyping. What kind of thing were you thinking would be better?  How about keys that work like texting on the phone? hold them down and they change to the accented version of them ?

Comment: @Psycogeek: But I’m more of a keyboarder.

Comment: http://www.ergonis.com/products/popcharx/features.html#Anchor-SearchField ?? there is one programmers idea of simpler.

Comment: @Psycogeek: what made you think I am using OSX?

Comment: Luckily I did not have to think, the program came in 2 flavors. I assumed you were talking about windows with NT4 and XP ?   Ok so the site bleeds mac all over it :-)  But what made you think it wasnt for windows too :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried the [Unicode IME](http://www.siao2.com/2005/05/18/419117.aspx), and it works. Now I have to remember all the codepoints.

---

## Unicode IME for Windows XP

You need to open the appropriate part of Control-Panel, In WIn-7 it is something like

- Open Control Panel
- Choose `Region and Language`
- Choose `Keyboards and Languages`,
- click <kbd>Change Keyboards</kbd>
- Select `Keyboard`

The linked page (dated 2005) describes (presumably for XP)

- Open `Add Input Language`
- Choose `Input Language` = `Chinese (Taiwan)`
- Select `Keyboard Layout/IME` = `Chinese (Traditional) - Unicode`

(Details obviously vary between Windows versions)

The linked page continues

> Simple to use -- just switch to it with  and start typing hex numbers in any application....
>   and then when you type a full Unicode code point, it will commit the character automatically!

## Unicode IME for Windows Vista and Windows 7

The official Microsoft "Unicode IME" described above was removed in Vista and is not present in Windows 7.

An MSDN Blog has some instructions for [Adding back a Unicode IME](http://www.siao2.com/2006/07/20/671835.aspx?PageIndex=2) - but it seems to have been a work in progress at that time.

I have installed this Unicode IME under Windows-7 64-bit and it works well.

To install the IME, you

- copy a [text file defining the IME](http://trigeminal.com/samples/IME/TableTextServiceUnicode.txt) into `\Program Files\Windows NT\TableTextService` and then
- open a command prompt with elevated privileges,
- `cd` to the above directory and
- type `rundll32 TableTextService.dll RegisterProfile TableTextServiceUnicode.txt`
- clicking OK on the confirmation dialogue.
- Then you can follow the instructions at the top of this answer to enable this IME.

## Using the Unicode IME

You press <kbd>Left Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> to switch to Unicode IME (or back again). The cursor shape changes to an underscore and the keyboard icon in the system notification area changes accordingly. If you then type four hex digits into Notepad (or other application?), the Unicode character for that Unicode code-point is inserted.

## IME Definition

Below is the start and end of the IME text-file definition, The copyright/licence for the [original](http://trigeminal.com/samples/IME/TableTextServiceUnicode.txt) is not clear but it appears to be intended to be freely available.

```
[System]
LangId = LANG_CHINESE, SUBLANG_CHINESE_TRADITIONAL
GuidProfile={ECD4D0E2-BC06-4726-AFB4-5EB43538B683}
Description="Unicode IME"
Display Description="Unicode IME"

[Configuration]
CandidateList.Phrase.HideWindow=1
CandidateList.Text.HideWindow=1
ReadingWindow.HideWindow=1
CandidateList.dontShowNextKeySequence=1
CandidateList.KeepCandidateListForInvalidKey=1
Composition.ConversionOnlyOneItem=1
Composition.QuitAndErrorOnConversion=1

[PreservedKey]
GuidImeMode={98213494-367A-4855-90A1-97D917E3EC3D}
KeyDefineImeMode=VK_SHIFT, TF_MOD_ON_KEYUP_SHIFT_ONLY
ImeMode=1

DoubleSingleByte=0
Punctuation=0

[LanguageBar]
EnableImeMode=0
EnableDoubleSingleByte=0
EnablePunctuation=0

[Profile]
KeystrokeFile ="%programFiles%\Windows NT\TableTextService\TableTextServiceUnicode.txt"
DictionaryFile="%programFiles%\Windows NT\TableTextService\TableTextServiceUnicode.txt"


[Keystroke.Composition]
VK_1,          0  = INPUT        // 1
VK_2,          0  = INPUT        // 2
VK_3,          0  = INPUT        // 3
VK_4,          0  = INPUT        // 4
VK_5,          0  = INPUT        // 5
VK_6,          0  = INPUT        // 6
VK_7,          0  = INPUT        // 7
VK_8,          0  = INPUT        // 8
VK_9,          0  = INPUT        // 9
VK_0,          0  = INPUT        // 0
VK_A,          0  = INPUT        // A
VK_B,          0  = INPUT        // B
VK_C,          0  = INPUT        // C
VK_D,          0  = INPUT        // D
VK_E,          0  = INPUT        // E
VK_F,          0  = INPUT        // F

[Text]
"0020" = " "
"0021" = "!"
"0022" ="
"0023" = "#"
"0024" = "$"
"0025" = "%"
"0026" = "&"
"0027" = "'"
"0028" = "("
"0029" = ")"
"002a" = "*"
"002b" = "+"
"002c" = ","
"002d" = "-"
"002e" = "."
"002f" = "/"
"0030" = "0"
"0031" = "1"
"0032" = "2"
"0033" = "3"
"0034" = "4"

middle part removed for brevity (and because copyright unclear)

"ffeb" = "￫"
"ffec" = "￬"
"ffed" = "￭"
"ffee" = "￮"
"fff9" = "￹"
"fffa" = "￺"
"fffb" = "￻"
"fffc" = "￼"
"fffd" = "�"
```

Answer (score 15):

This can be achieved with an [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com) script.

#### The script

```
<!1::Numpad1
<!2::Numpad2
<!3::Numpad3
<!4::Numpad4
<!5::Numpad5
<!6::Numpad6
<!7::Numpad7
<!8::Numpad8
<!9::Numpad9
<!0::Numpad0
<!+::NumpadAdd
```

#### How it works

The line `<!1::Numpad1` simulates pressing the key <kbd>1</kbd> on the numeric keypad when the key combination on the left side of `::` is pressed.

Here, `<!` represents the left <kbd>Alt</kbd> key and `1` the key <kbd>1</kbd>.

As a result, pressing you can use the "regular" as if they were on the numeric keypad.

Note:

- If your keyboards has two <kbd>Alt</kbd> keys (rather than an <kbd>AltGr</kbd> key), you can make this work with the right <kbd>Alt</kbd> key as well. It suffices to remove all `<` characters.
- The line `<!+::NumpadAdd` is only needed if you want to [type Unicode characters using hexadecimal codes](https://superuser.com/q/13086).

#### How to use

1. [Download](http://www.autohotkey.com/download/) and install the latest version of AutoHotkey.
2. Save the above script as `numpad.ahk`, using your favorite text editor.
3. Double-click the file to run the script.
4. If you wish, copy the script (or a link to it) in the `Startup` folder.

Comment: Sweet! I tried to replace the `<!` with a `<^>!` to use AltGr instead of AltLeft but it won't work. Any idea why?

Comment: @CAFxX: That works as far as mapping `1` to `Num1` goes. The problem is that you're still pressing the `AltGr` key, not `Alt` alone (which wouldn't work with the real numpad either). There might be a way around it, but I can't see it. You could post a new question.