# How to define custom keys in a keyboard - Windows

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, keyboard-navigation

I am using a laptop having Windows Vista. It lacks a numpad. But I want a numpad, without having an external keyboard, for some reason. I have a `Fn` key for special functions like screen brightness, volume control etc. I saw numpads in some laptops, which allows numpas in some keys (10 letter with or without some character keys in the pattern of numpad), by pressing along with `Fn` key. Is is possible to define it manually so that I can define numpad on some keys?

Comment: I would normally suggest Autohotkey, and there are a few scripts created to simulate numpad keys. Unfortunately, it's not always possible to detect the `Fn` key: this depends a lot on which brand, and possibly even model, of laptop you have. It's necessary information, unless you're happy to use a substitute key or key combination to activate the numpad.

Comment: More answers can be found in https://superuser.com/questions/201666/how-do-i-get-a-special-character-on-a-netbook-without-a-number-pad/1691207

Comment: Further solutions/answers can be found in https://superuser.com/questions/201666/how-do-i-get-a-special-character-on-a-netbook-without-a-number-pad/1691207

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create your own keyboard layout, based on a stock layout. [MSKLC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964665.aspx) is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

[AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) should be able to solve this for you.

> AutoHotkey is a free, open-source utility for Windows. With it, you can:
>
> - Automate almost anything by sending keystrokes and mouse clicks. You can write a mouse or keyboard macro by hand or use the macro recorder.
> - Create hotkeys for keyboard, joystick, and mouse. Virtually any key, button, or combination can become a hotkey.
> - Expand abbreviations as you type them. For example, typing "btw" can automatically produce "by the way".
> - Create custom data-entry forms, user interfaces, and menu bars. See GUI for details.
> - Remap keys and buttons on your keyboard, joystick, and mouse.
> - Respond to signals from hand-held remote controls via the WinLIRC client script.
> - Run existing AutoIt v2 scripts and enhance them with new capabilities.
> - Convert any script into an EXE file that can be run on computers that don't have AutoHotkey installed.

Comment: @DragonLord , why edit an old post?

Comment: This was essentially a link-only answer before the edit.  See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers