# Full Unicode keypad entry in Chrome (including E/F digits?)

Tags: google-chrome, unicode

I frequently find myself using my keypad to enter Unicode characters, since it's much faster to type, e.g. ALT+2B50 ALT+FE0F than to dig around `charmap` or the Googles to find that character to copy/paste.

Unfortunately, I can't do that character, or others like it, when typing into a text input box in Chrome, because the ALT-F keypress is intercepted by Chrome to pop open the menu. (ALT-E does the same thing.)

Is there a way to tell Chrome, either permanently or temporarily, that I really do want the ALT-F and ALT-E keypress to count as text input, and not as `accesskey`-commands?

Comment: If you have the Tampermonkey add-on installed in Chrome you can use [this userscript](https://github.com/calraith/gm_scripts/blob/master/Alt+Num_Extended_Char_Entry.user.js) to convert `U+2B50` to `⭐` by typing `2B50` and hitting Alt+X (like in MS Word).  (`FE0F` would probably work as well, but I have no fonts with a glyph for that character.)  [Full details](https://superuser.com/a/1216294/204705).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install [Shortkeys (Custom Keyboard Shortcuts)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/shortkeys-custom-keyboard/logpjaacgmcbpdkdchjiaagddngobkck?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog) extension and disable at least (see also [Chrome keyboard shortcuts](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179?hl=en))

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> (Chrome default: Jump to the Address Bar);
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> (Chrome default: Open the Menu):

[image: Shortkeys]