# Typing a Unicode RLM on Windows XP with a numpad-less keyboard

Tags: windows-xp, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, unicode, right-to-left

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Typing strange letters¿ w/o numpad?](https://superuser.com/questions/55502/typing-strange-letters-w-o-numpad)

My desktop keyboard doesn't have a numpad:

[image: numpad-less keyboard]

And I like it that way because it saves space on my desk.

However, I want to be able to insert a [Unicode RLM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-to-left_mark) with my keyboard. Is there any way to do that?

(I use Windows XP.)

Comment: Laptop keyboards (which this resembles) often have a numlock button that turns part of the keyboard (the letter keys under the right hand) into a numeric keyboard. Does your keyboard have such a feature?

Comment: No, they aren't.

Comment: I find none of the answers there satisfactory. The Alt-X method doesn't work on enough apps.

Comment: @Chris Nava: Some high-ranking person edited my last comment and now it sounds flippant, sorry about that. I meant, my specific keyboard doesn't have a numpad like you describe.

Comment: @cool-RR: No problem.  I realized I should have made a comment not an answer after posting.

Comment: I understand that you found none of the duplicate posts' answers satisfactory @cool-RR, perhaps post a comment or put a bounty on the other question, as this question is a dupe, it asks the *same* question.