# Is there a key combo that's usable for Unicode characters in the same manner as ASCII characters?

Tags: unicode, special-characters, ascii, ascii-art

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Typing strange letters¿ w/o numpad?](https://superuser.com/questions/55502/typing-strange-letters-w-o-numpad)

If you open up Window's Character Map and select, say, Arial as the font then you're obviously shown all of the characters that Arial can possibly produce. Of course, our keyboards don't have buttons for all of these possible chars (think of the SIZE of the things if they did! :) )

Using the character map you can copy and paste whatever char that you happen to need. This can get quite inconvenient, so if you know the ASCII key code then you can use that instead. For instance: If I want to make the Spanish upside-down question mark (¿) then I can hold down ALT , press 168 or 0191 on the numpad and after releasing ALT then my purdy little not-on-my-keyboard char appears. For chars that you don't know the code for offhand then the Character Map ever so handily tells you what they are in the bottom-right hand side of the application.

**My question is this: *For Unicode characters that don't show a keystroke, is there a different keystroke syntax you can use for that?*** As an example in Arial there is a character that looks exactly like a backwards capital S described as "U+01A7 Latin Capital Letter Tone Two", but no corresponding ASCII-style ALT+whatevernumbers. I'll paste it here - **Ƨ** - and hope that it actually shows up on the page and not as either a blank spot or as something else. If the char between the dashes doesn't look like a backwards S then that's not it.

**So - is there a Unicode keystroke pattern?** Something like holding down ALT and SHIFT then typing out 01A7 then releasing the SHIFT and ALT? If there does happen to be a Unicode keystroke pattern then Mr. Sootah will be a very happy man-child indeed. :)