# How to write Unicode character in Microsoft Word using character's code?

Tags: microsoft-word, unicode

I am trying to write a Unicode character in Microsoft Word by using its hex code; e.g., WHITE SQUARE (◻) code `25A1`? 
How do I do it?

Comment: Also, [Does Unicode have a unified way to input all diacritics, especially in MS Word 2010?](https://superuser.com/q/659312/150988), [Insert Unicode characters via the keyboard](https://superuser.com/q/47420/150988), [How to type the U+200C character directly with keyboard](https://superuser.com/q/1410431/150988) and [How do I type the infinity character in a web browser?](https://superuser.com/q/557356/150988)

Comment: farooq: Please search the site for an existing question before you post a new one, even if you know the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type the hex code and place the cursor next to it (or select it)
and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>.