# Many charcters are not displayed in programs

Tags: windows-7, fonts, characters

I am using Windows 7 and for some reason a lot of mathematical characters do not display for me:[image: ex1] [image: ex2]

Could anyone please help me out on how this can be fixed?

Comment: Try `sfc /scannow` from an elevated command prompt. Maybe some required system fonts are missing.

Comment: Trying it right now, will let you know how it goes, thanks!

Comment: Try to update the display driver from the manufacturer's website.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of research I found what exactly the problem was !

**Your issue is that Unicode characters are displayed as squares .... !!**

and this question was already answered [here](https://superuser.com/questions/302672/how-to-make-windows-show-unicode-characters-properly)hope this answer solves your query..

**2.Other way around:**

You can use applocale to display such buggy programs correctly.
[AppLocale](http://www.entroducing.com/view/non-unicode-program-displaying-chinese-characters-as-boxsquare-in-windows-7)

**3.You can try these settings:**

1.Go to "Control Panel" -> "Region and Language" -> "Administrative" -> "Change system locale..."

2.Change the locale to the one you're having problem with, and then change it back.

[image: regional and language settings]

Cheers !!!

Answer (score 0):

You can also try and [change the default fonts](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1175-fonts-change.html).