# What is this '°͌͌͌͌͌͌͌͌͌͌͌͌͌͌͌͌͌͌͌͌͌͌͌͌͌' strange character?

Tags: encoding, character-encoding

I saw this

```
°͌͌͌͌͌͌͌͌͌͌͌͌͌͌͌͌͌͌͌͌͌͌͌͌͌
```

strange character online. I also noted that:

1. It needs 26 backspaces to delete but behaves like one character when selecting.
2. It is drawn vertically covering many rows above.
   [image: Strange looking character]
   What is this character and why is it behaving like this ?

Comment: On [so]: [How does Zalgo text work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6579844/how-does-zalgo-text-work)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It's stacked [diacritics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic) on top of one another, as [seen here](http://www.siao2.com/2006/02/17/533929.aspx), and in the [infamous zalgo text](http://www.marlborotech.com/Zalgo.html); in this case stacked accents used in many non-English Latin-based languages.

Specifically, it seems to be a [tilde](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tilde), used as an accent.

Credit where credit is due, it uses the same techniques used for the faces in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/52671/which-unicode-characters-do-smilies-like-consist-of).

Comment: In other words, [Unicode subscripts, superscripts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts)  and diacritics **can** be abused to produce unreadable and overflowing text.

Comment: yup, or to render more complex scripts simply ;p