# What are these strange characters?

Tags: encoding, unicode, character-encoding

I couldn't put them in the title because they actually seem to have many bytes:

I took some screenshots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: very strange characters, they seem to have lines shooting up the screen on my computer!  http://i.imgur.com/AJ1ghBQ.png

Comment: These characters prevent us from being able to edit your question.  Can you post a screenshot of the characters instead?

Comment: @barlop | Not just yours ;)

Comment: There's only about a dozen duplicates of this... gimme a minute.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This question is a duplicate of the [question](https://superuser.com/questions/432015/what-is-this-strange-character) @Bob linked. To expand on the accepted answer to that question, [Unicode supports stacking diacritics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character), so what you're actually seeing are a whole bunch of characters, but part of their definition is that they get stacked on top of the previous character.

Consider the Spanish character, [`Ñ`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%91). It is really an `N` with a `~` displayed above. While many combo characters are pre-made and available in Unicode (and even ANSI), Unicode supports making the many variations that non-Latin alphabets require.

Answer (score 2):

According to a Google search they are Thai. See  [here](http://www.thai-language.com/id/143591)

Comment: Yes, is the same character, but this Thai has just 1 byte per character.