# Wingdings font in Firefox 3.5?

Tags: firefox

How can I display [Wingdings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wingdings) characters in Firefox 3.5?

```
http://www.purplehell.com/riddletools/wingdingschart.htm
```

This page will render the special characters in IE6 but does not show the correct symbols in Firefox 3.5.

Comment: In what OS are you having the problems?

Comment: Tried both Mac OS 10.5 and OpenSolaris.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firefox deliberately does not support webdings and wingdings.  See [this "bug"](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=424610).  "Specifying Wingdings font is contrary to the published specifications, has never been a documented feature of HTML, is not reliable, and should not be done", according to [this](http://www.alanwood.net/demos/wingdings.html), which explains that you should be using unicode characters instead.

Answer (score 0):

Though the question is about Dingbats, not Wingdings: maybe the note on using "Arial Unicode MS" at [Get Dingbats to appear in Firefox 3?](https://superuser.com/questions/14087/get-dingbats-to-appear-in-firefox-3) can help.